# How to set Github Actions as Required Status Checks

Tags: github, github-actions

I would like to set my GitHub Actions as required status checks so that I would be able to have protected branches and prevent commits from being pushed to specific branches if they don’t pass the github actions checks.
But when I go to the branch protection rules, the github actions don’t appear in the list of checks to choose from:
[image: Repository Branch Protection Rules Do Not Show GitHub Actions]

As you can see here I do have two github actions that have been running for several weeks on my repo:

[image: GitHub Actions That Exist in the Repository]

So am I missing something? How do I set Github Actions as required status checks?

Comment: I had the same issue finding documentation on this. Where is the simple step-by-step guide, right? I searched "github branch protection rule workflow" and "github action branch protection rule" and found nothing. It was a full day of searching their docs and guides before I found it was this easy.

Comment: @AmritKahlon see the answer below. Just start typing the name of the job in the textbox and GitHub will autocomplete it (assuming that the yml file you have is in the .github/workflows folder within your repository)

Comment: I used the answer below.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can still find your status check at search by name of the GitHub action job.

```
name: .NET

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    etc...
```

Here is name of the job is **build**.

[image: Search example]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's so simple but I couldn't find any explanation as to how to do this anywhere. It works great now.

Comment: I wonder if this is a bug of some description as this doesn't always occur, but happened to me today for the first time.

Comment: Great! But what's the point to have the same check (build) both in the Action (on -> pull_request) and in the Branch protection rule page? Isn't redundant? Or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: @toto if you defined in the branch protection rules the setting "Require a pull request before merging" then this would be redundant since it would not be possible to push to main without first doing a pull request. However, if you did not check that checkbox in the branch protection rules then you could still push without a pull request and in such a case this would not be redundant.

Comment: @EyalGerber ok thanks. In case is redundant (both checkbox enabled and in the Action) the check is however executed only once, right?

Comment: @toto , you are correct because the check associated with 'push' is associated with the main branch only. If the push were not associated with a specific branch, then you would have a redundancy of checks too, and for each push on the pull request branch, you would have gotten two checks of both the pull request and the push.

Comment: @EyalGerber thanks. However even with a 'push' associated with a main branch only the check would be twice. After a successful 'pull_request' isn't there a real push to the main branch? Where it would trigger the 'push' check as well (following the above code example)? You said already that it would be redundant (with  the setting "Require a pull request before merging" enabled)

Comment: @toto yes, it would still trigger the check again, and it would be redundant even if you set the checkbox "Require a pull request before merging." What I meant when I said that if that setting is checked that there wonʻt be redundancy was that in cases where you push to main without a pull request, then the check would occur once due to the push. However, in case of a pull request, you would still have redundancy. The only way I know how to avoid redundancy is by writing in the yml file: `on: [push, pull_request] `, but this will apply to all branches, but no double testing occurs (tested).

Comment: @toto' In the Action itself, that's simply a trigger. When we add the job on the Github Settings page, we're requiring that job to succeed before the PR can be merged.

Comment: Is this answer working for y'all? For me, I require `build` to pass, yet on the PR, when it runs, it shows the workflow name, `.NET`. So it says `.NET` succeeded, but `build` is still pending information. WTH? I can change the requirement to `.NET`, but then that is thwarted by env vars appearing after the name. I can't get it to work. It should be such a simple feature.

Answer (score 3):

Give a name to a Job

```
jobs:
  build:
    name: Code Formatting
```

otherwise, it gives a `build` as a default name

And on the setting page, it gives suggestions whenever you start searching by job name.